# MySQL replication Error 'You cannot 'ALTER' a log table if logging is enabled' on query

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-error-1064, database-replication

MySQL replication got broken with the last error being

> Last_Errno: 1580 Last_Error: Error 'You cannot 'ALTER' a log table if
>   logging is enabled' on query. Default database: 'mysql'.

Seems this is the fault of running mysql_upgrade for version 5.1.61
I've found a few bug reports but didn't find how to remedy the situation once the upgrade has already been performed on the master.

Any ideas?

Refs:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39133
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43579
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46638

Comment: This sounds indeed like this bug to me: [MySQL bug #43579](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43579)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Seems I'll be answering my own question. Trying to alter a log table while logging in enabled creates the error. I really don't understand how the MASTER could execute that query as it has the same logging in place and if it did, then why can't the SLAVE do the same? I'll be happy to read explanations but for now let's focus on the solution.

To see the error that broke the replication execute

> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
>   and you will see the trouble making query

You can now stop the slave

> STOP SLAVE;

Disable the relevant logs (don't copy+paste this but check your own configuration first!):

> SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';

Restart the slave

> START SLAVE;

See no errors are shown on

> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G

and enable the relevant logs again:

> SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: don't need to disable sql_log_bin.

Comment: Disabling sql_log_bin is unnecessary and much more dangerous than temporarily disabling slow_query_log. Daniel Caillibaud's answer is safer.

Comment: Great! Worked perfectly, and spared the need to recreate the slave

Answer (score 23):

I have a master-master replication, so I can't stop binary logs on slave but

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = "OFF";
START SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = "ON";
```

solved my pb

Comment: Curious, but why re-enable the slow_query_log on the slave if it's known to cause the problem?  What value is there in having that turned on on the slave when it's already enabled on the master?

Comment: @jwg2s the slave will typically have different read-only queries executed on it (unless it's purely for backup), so you will want to know if any of those are slow too